# What is the 'label' column here in California housing example of Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning

https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/california-housing-data-description

I have also attached a snap but I am confused which column(s) is label? and which columns are features? According to my understanding, **median_house_value** is label while all other columns are features?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The choice of label and features depends on your application. If you want to learn the location of expensive houses, then the latitude/longitude would be the label, and the other items the features. If you want to predict the house price from location and age of the house, then the median house value is the label.

When deciding on the features, not all of them might be relevant. I would suggest doing a correlation analysis before choosing features, as you might find that age and value don't correlate, ie the age variable would contribute very little to the learning outcome.